# Не отправляется имя элемента при отправке формы

Tags: javascript, html, submit

Есть форма, у которой раньше была кнопка `<button>` с типом `submit` и именем `R`. При нажатии на эту кнопку происходила отправка формы. И отправлялось имя этой кнопки.

```
<button class="btn btn-default2" type="submit" name="R" onclick="if(!checkForm(this.form)) {return false }">Зарегистрировать</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решил добавить немного логики и теперь при `onclick` у меня идет запрос на сервер для проверки некоего условия, потом проверка `checkForm` и в конце вызывается сабмит формы.

```
<button class="btn btn-default2" type=button name=R onclick="
                var that = this;
                $.post('/ajax/someAdditionalCheck.php', 'id=' + id).done(function(r) {                    
                if (r.error) {
                    showModalWin(r.error.message, 'Ошибка!');
                    return false;
                }

                if(!checkForm(this.form)) {
                    return false;
                }

                that.form.submit();
            });
            return false;"

    >Зарегистрировать</button>
```

и вот при таком коде форма отправляется, но имя этого поля не передается. 
Тип менял и обратно на `submit`, все равно одно и то же.

Вопрос: Почему? И как сделать, чтобы оно (имя поля) отправлялось вместе с остальными? Желательно без создания динамически нового поля с добавлением в эту форму (ибо костыль).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос: Почему?

Правильный вопрос ).

Потому что при стандартной отправке формы браузер добавляет `name=value` нажатой кнопки с `type="submit"` в отправляемые данные, так как известно, что нажатие этой кнопки явилось причиной отправки.

В Вашем новом сценарии, стандартный сабмит отменен с помощью `return false;` (и потому что `type="button"`) и `that.form.submit();` вызывается асинхронно, когда `onclick` уже давно отработал.

Решение, если на сервере необходим элемент данных запроса `"R"`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="R" value="submit" /> // внутри формы, и это не костыль

document.getElementById("R").setAttribute("name", "R");
that.form.submit();
```

Comment: "`that.form.submit();` вызывается асинхронно, когда `onclick` уже давно отработал." -- у меня  `that.form.submit();` срабатывает после ajax запроса, потому что в блоке `.done()` находится)) С этим нет проблем.  А получается, что ваш вариант, что динамически написать `createElement` с нужным именем добавив форму  - одно и то же? И мое решение (создание динамически элемента временного) в итоге тоже не является костыльным, как я думал?

Comment: @СергейМишин да, не является

Comment: Понятно. Хорошо, как попробую - вернусь)